# Asking which way is better

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation, software-engineering-se, code-review-se

I have a coding question with two compilable options. I want to ask which is better and why. Code review, programmers, stack exchange...im not really sure? Where is this question appropriate.

It may be an opinion based question and it may not. I don't really know until I know the answer. Like I said, both ways produce the same results, but I don't know which is the better practice.

What site does this belong on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This definitely belongs CodeReview with the tag: [comparative-review](/questions/tagged/comparative-review) this fits exactly what the site is about.

Just for sanity, going through the checklist:

1. Is code included directly in my question? (See Make sure you include your code in your question below.) - check
2. Is the code your code (you wrote it, or you 'own' it) - hmmm?
3. Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code? - check.
4. Do I want the code to be good code? (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar) - check.
5. To the best of my knowledge, does the code work? - check.
6. Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code? - check.

Comment: Added in the missing checklist item.... is the code your code. Code Review is not for understanding, or evaluating someone else's code.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! What should I do if my code is generic example code to illustrate my question?

Comment: @Evorlor Then you have a problem, since your code fails the "example code" clause. It might be possible to circumvent this by writing a "full blown" implementation and have that reviewed instead.

Comment: That's what I'll do then. I'll fit in some other comparison questions that way too. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

We have had several such questions in the past, and while "A vs. B" questions are not what we like the most, they are often acceptable providing that **[the code is real, actual code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243) and not "example code" that has been stripped of context**.

In addition to your language tag, use the [tag comparative-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review) and read through some of those questions to see which ones were successful...